# Refactoring of a large cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake

I recently joined a project which uses cmake and has lots of magic going on. I have some experience in setting up cmake for smaller projects, but this one seems a mess to me.

The project consists of several applications and libraries which share one, main library (developed by us) and several small ones (partly external, partly our own), some of which share dependancies and some not. Because of a very specific distribution model, one of the most important requirements is that every application and library can be compiled 'independently'. In other words, I should be able to enter every one of the directories and go with mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make. Obviously, I should be able to do it in the parent directories as well. Currently it is accomplished in the following way:

1. Almost every folder is a separate cmake project.
2. Every library and application which has a dependancy on other libraries or includes includes specific Install+Find script in its CMakeLists.txt. For example, the InstallLib1Internal.cmake looks at the current build directory. If the Lib1Internal library and includes are there, it just returns, if not it configures, compiles and installs libraries and includes to the build directory. Everything's done using execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} [...]). Then, the FindLib1Internal.cmake decides whether to look for headers and libraries, adds libraries and dependancies and sets relevant *_DIRS/FOUND and other variables.

The files structure is more or less as follows:

```
root/
    app1/
        app1-1/
            include/
            src/
            CMakeLists.txt
        app1-2/
            include/
            src/
            CMakeLists.txt
        app1-3/
            include/
            src/
            CMakeLists.txt
        CMakeLists.txt
    app2/
        include/
        src/
        CMakeLists.txt
    cmake
        FindLib1Internal.cmake
        FindLib2Internal.cmake
        FindLib3External.cmake
        InstallLib1Internal.cmake
        InstallLib2Internal.cmake
        InstallLib3External.cmake
    shared/
        lib1_internal/
            include/
            src/
            CMakeLists.txt
        lib2_internal/
            include/
            src/
            CMakeLists.txt
        lib3_external/
            include/
            src/
            CMakeLists.txt
    CMakeLists.txt
```

There are many issues I see with this approach.

1. If the internal library is modified, we won't see the changes because the only check is done in the build directory.
2. For every project the compilation of all components is done in the current project's build directory. If the components compilation took place in their folders, then they could be shared for all projects without the need to recompile them.
3. The Install/Finds are copied and almost identical for most of the CMakeLists.txt, adding a new one or modifying anything is a real pain.
4. For some reason I feel like this solution is hackish, but I haven't seen any other way to make every project buildable.
5. Install in cmake's logic isn't what we do - I think it should be used for installing stuff in the user's system rather than copying headers and libraries in the building process.

Ideally, I want to get rid of the scripts and rely only on the CMakeLists and their dependancies.  However, I cannot make small changes and test them because cmake fails with various errors everytime I modify anything. It feels like I'm playing Jenga with most of the tower already gone...

It would be great if anyone could recommend any global changes in order to simplify the cmake structure. I find it hard to believe, but maybe the current organization and the method is correct?

Comment: off-topic comment: the change you wish to make is pretty big: changing the entire build process of your project consisting of many intertwined libraries. And you are new to the project. Make sure that the powers that be and everyone involved are ok with this.

Comment: `Because of a very specific distribution model, one of the most important requirements is that every application and library can be compiled 'independently'.` - is your project open-source or not? In other words, whether you need to independently distribute **sources** or only **executables** (with needed libraries and other deliverables)?

Comment: So far it's not really open-source. However, sometimes we 'distribute' sources, sometimes executables, sometimes both - it depends on the context. If we distribute sources, they need to be compilable, so we deliver them with all headers and libraries - in source or binary form.

Comment: As you bother about cmake install logic (p.4 in issues list), your root project includes subprojects via `add_subdirectory()`, doesn't it? Another question: Whether it is acceptible to distribute subproject sources in a way, that they are **differ** from the ones under the root project? (So, if your `app1` uses `lib1_internal` library, full directory `shared/lib1_internal` could be copied under `app1` directory before `app1` source distribution).

Comment: Yes, the root project adds all application directories via add_subdirectory. Because of this every subdirectory's CMakeLists invokes the same Install/Find scripts in order to find and copy the libraries and headers. Regarding distribution - yes, it's possible, we have packaging scripts which do that after the build.